# How to insert an array of ids with create function in node

Tags: arrays, object, mongoose, insert, create-function

I Have defined this mongoose schema in node

```
`const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tour: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Tour',
      required: [true, 'Booking must belong to Tours!'],
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: [true, 'Booking must belong to User!'],
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Booking must have a price'],
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  paid: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});
bookingSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate('user').populate({
    path: 'tour',
    select: 'name',
  });`your text`
});

Then when i try to create a booking i use the create function 
await Booking.create({ tour, user, price });`
```

the tour param is an array of ids

but i get this error
"Booking validation failed: tour.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["5c88fa8cf4afda39709c295a,5c88fa8cf4afda39709c2951"]" (type string) at path "tour.0"
I can do it with only one tour if the tour property wasnt an  array of objects. My main issue is that a booking can be related to many tour objects in my database
*edit after some modifications the error become
"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

My front end code(angular) is this. I am making a get request to my backend(node)

```
createBookingCheckout(params: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log('serv');
    return this.http.get<any>(`${CREATE_BOOKING_CHECKOUT}`, {
      params,
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

So i pass the ids as query param

And this is the backend where i am trying to create the booking

```
exports.createBookingCheckout = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { order, tour: strTour } = req.query;
  const user = req.user._id;
  const parsedOrder = JSON.parse(order);
  const tour = JSON.parse(strTour);
  console.log(tour);
  // const tours = await tour.forEach((id) => {
  //   Tour.find({ id });
  // });
  // console.log(tours);

  let price = 0;
  parsedOrder.forEach(
    (obj) => (price = price + obj.price_data.unit_amount * obj.quantity)
  );
  if (!parsedOrder && !user) return next();
  await Booking.create({ tour, user, price });
  res.redirect(req.originalUrl.split('?')[0]);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick solution to this is that whenever you are going to add more than a tour you should create an array push all tours IDs to the array and then add the tourArray to the new Booking that you are going to create, and when you are going to update an existing Booking, you should repeat the process.

When you are going to create a new Booking document.

**Scenario 1 : with one Tour**

- You just pass the id of the tour {always check if the tour exist}, that's obvious and simple, at the same time mongo is going to create a table referring to the model as Tour is defined as many within your Booking model

**Scenario 2 : with more than one Tour**

- You need to define all the Tour's IDs in an array within the body

```
{
    "tour": [ "id-1", "id-2", ...]
}
```

**Updating a Booking**

say that you are going to add a new Tour to an existing Booking,

```js
Booking.findByIdAndUpdate(
        {_id: id},
        {
         // ! here all your other data

            $push: {tour: new_tour}
        },
// this is just to return the updated booking
        {new: true, runValidators: true}
}
```

=> the operator `$push` in mongoose is what you need to push into the existing array or tour that's already in your existing Booking
The `new_tour` is coming from your `req.body`

as for sure in some cases you are going to delete a `Tour` ID from a `Booking`,

=> in that case you are going to use the operator `$pull`

Comment: I think that this is what i am doiing right now. The tour param in the create function is an array of ids. I am creating this array with this code const tour = req.body.map((item) => item.tour.id); But this implementation creates the problem i posted.

Comment: const tour = req.body.map((item) => item.tour.id)
do you have a map in your body, or you are trying to use the map function can you please share the code  or why don't you map over the tour variable
tour.map( ...)

Comment: am editing my answer so that it will be more visible

Comment: i have also edited my quesion to clarify a little bit more and sorry for not been very specific. Its my first time posting here and i am trying to get used to it

Comment: can you check please I just create a simple project that goes with the two scenarios that I have described; if you need I'll give you the GitHub repo

Comment: thank's for the answer. The first error (about the cast) was because tour was an JSON and i had to convert it. The second error originate from this line of code res.redirect(req.originalUrl.split('?')[0]). So even thought the server repsoned with error the booking was actually created but i didnt check the database. So i guess i am stupid. Anyway thanks a lot